# I am not able to use my Variables it gives me error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field"

Tags: java, static-methods

I am trying to access global variables I am getting an error

```java
public class FinalKeyword {

    int x=20;
    String n= "Broad";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field

Comment: `static int x=20; static String n= "Bhakar";`

Comment: Y i have to add static keyword

Comment: `x` and `n` are *instance* fields. `main` is a static method - there aren't any instances of `FinalKeyword` until you create one. Which instance would you expect it to take the values of `x` and `n` from?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: Got it Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

`Non-static` member (field, method or block without a `static` modifier) belongs to *instance*;

`Static` member belongs to class.

You can't use a member of instance, if you don't have an instance.

```
FinalKeyword fk = new FinalKeyword();
int x = fk.x; //this will work, as you're accessing a "x" instance member.
String y = fk.n; //same here.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot helping with me basics

Comment: @AkulaBhaskar Generally, when you want to say "thank you", better to upvote and accept the answer which helps you.

Comment: sure thing it certainly helped